# Two Thread tasks in Winforms Continuously Checking Back

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently trying to keep a counter on C# on a local file folder for new files that are created.

I have two sub directories to CD and LP that I have to keep checking. With counters that makes sure that the count of folders made have not exceeded the count set by the user.

```
public static int LPmax { get; set; }
public static int CDmax { get; set; }

public static int LPcounter2 { get; set; }
public static int CDcounter2 { get; set; } 

public static int LPCreated;
public static int CDCreated;
public static int oldLPCreated;
public static int oldCDCreated;

FileSystemWatcher CDdirWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
FileSystemWatcher LPdirWatcher = new   FileSystemWatcher();
```

```
//watch method should run in the background as checker
public void watch()
{ 
        CDdirWatcher.Path = @"C:\Data\LotData\CD";
        CDdirWatcher.Filter = "EM*";
        CDdirWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        CDdirWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        CDdirWatcher.Created += CDdirWatcher_Created;


        LPdirWatcher.Path = @"C:\Data\LotData\LP";
        LPdirWatcher.Filter = "EM*";
        LPdirWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        LPdirWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        LPdirWatcher.Created += LPdirWatcher_Created;
        Thread.Sleep(10); 
}
private static void CDdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
    CDCreated += 1;
}
private static void LPdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
    LPCreated += 1;
}
```

The above method works fine, and the criteria is that it has to be less count then the one set

```
public void checker()
{
    if(CDCreated>CDmax)
    {
        popupbx();
    }
    if(LPCreated>LPmax)
    {
        popupbx();
    }
}
```

The problem is my main method where I have two threads which need to continuously check the two criteria to see if the counter has been exceeded.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Implementing Threads asynchronously
    Thread oThreadone = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Do what u wanna……
        watch();
    });

    Thread oThreadtwo = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Do what u wanna……
        checker();
    });

    //Calling thread workers
    oThreadone.Start(); 
    oThreadone.IsBackground = true; 
    oThreadtwo.Start();
    oThreadtwo.IsBackground = true;
}
```

Mkdir fires the counters in debug mode, but thread two doesn't check for the counters after they fire.

Comment: And the “problem” is? At the least, code should marshal UI operations back on the UI thread.. see keywords used there. Also, using threads at all seems problematic: there is nothing to loop. The file watcher runs asynchronously already.

Comment: I really think my first method needs a background thread though because it needs to continuously run and check back for new folders made and maybe yeah the counter doesn't need to be in a thread. But I really am not too sure here

Comment: The Filewatcher provides information via asynchronous callbacks much like a “Button Click” event. It uses threads (or other concurrency methods) internally. There is no need to keep recreating it (ie. in a loop) nor is there any blocking method that must be called to ensure it executes.

Comment: yea, it's probably is not a great usage\project to learn threading on - as the type you're using isn't being used correctly like this; with that said, the answer here should really be for the sake of addressing the issue and expectation here.

Comment: Is it still possible for my application to be in the background and show a pop up once the limit has been reached?

Comment: we'll probably discuss or suggest alternatives after this specific problem in this question is addressed - lets just focus on grooming it for reproducible scope first.  how are you applying this *... makes sure that the count of folders made have not exceeded the count*, is it in `popupbx()`? does it manage the threads or `FileSystemWatcher` instances?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. So popupbox() only calls the popup, checker() is the method that is the condition where the limit must not be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first major thing wrong with your code is that neither of threads you create are needed, nor do they do what you want. Specifically, the `FileSystemWatcher` object itself is already asynchronous, so you can create it in the main thread. In fact, you should, because there you could set `FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject` to the current form instance so that it will raise its events in that object's synchronization context. I.e. your event handlers will be executed in the main thread, which is what you want.

So the first method, `watch()`, rather than being executed in a thread, just call it directly.

Which brings me to the second method, `checker()`. Your method for the thread doesn't loop, so it will execute the two tests, and then promptly exit. That's the end of that thread. It won't stay around long enough to monitor the counts as they are updated.

You could fix it by looping in the `checker()` method, so that it never exits. But then you run into problems of excessive CPU usage. Which you'll fix by adding sleep statements. Which then you're wasting a thread most of the time. Which you could fix by using `async`/`await` (e.g. `await Task.Delay()`). Except that would just unnecessarily complicate the code.

Instead, you should just perform each check after each count is updated. In theory, you could just display the message immediately. But that will block the event handler subscribed to `FileSystemWatcher`, possibly delaying additional reports. So you may instead prefer to use `Control.BeginInvoke()` to defer display of the message until after the event handler has returned.

So, taking all that into account, your code might instead look more like this:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    watch();
}

private void CDdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
    CDCreated += 1;
    if (CDCreated > CDmax)
    {
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)popupbx);
    }
}

private static void LPdirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{ 
    LPCreated += 1;
    if (LPCreated > LPmax)
    {
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)popupbx);
    }
}
```

You can remove the `checker()` method altogether. The `watch()` method can remain as it is, though I would change the order of subscribing to the `Created` event and the assignment of `EnableRaisingEvents`. I.e. don't enable raising events until you've already subscribed to the event. The `FileSystemWatcher` is unreliable enough as it is, without you giving it a chance to raise an event before you're ready to observe it. :)

This is based on your current implementation. Note though that if files keep getting created, the message will be displayed over and over. If they are created fast enough, new messages will be displayed before the user can dismiss the previously-displayed one(s). You may prefer to modify your code to prevent this. E.g. unsubscribe from the event after you've already exceeded the max count, or at least temporarily inhibit the display of the message while one such message is already being displayed. Exactly what to do is up to you, and beyond the scope of your question and thus the scope of this answer.

Comment: As a side note, the events should be subscribe to before setting `.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`. It's also quite preferable - expecially when the FSW object(s) are created in the Form's constructor or otherwise before the Form.Load event is raised - to initialize the FSW objects in a [BeginInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.begininit)/ [EndInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.endinit) block.